# What size should Android pre-Gingerbread HDPI notification bar icons be?

Tags: android, android-layout

What size should Android pre-Gingerbread HDPI notification bar icons be?

In the documentation it says for MDPI 25x25 with a 2-pixel safeframe, i.e. 21x21:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Using the standard 50% upscaler for HDPI, 21*1.5 = 31.5. So should they be 32x32 + 3 + 3 = 38x38, or 31x31 + 3 + 3 = 37x37? I want a value that won't get auto-scaled :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets) has values of:
19 x 19 px
25 x 25 px
38 x 38 px

Comment: Link now redirects to a not-so-helpful page. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the accepted answer has changed to a redirect... it appears that Google have decided to retire the docs for pre-4.0 notification icons. It must have happened recently because I was reading that document just a couple of weeks ago.

I wasn't able to find the original Android page anywhere, but I stumbled across the following link which is even better! It contains the above information about notification icons for older Android versions and more.

http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/

Answer (score -1):

instead of using a table and create your own files , you can use:
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html#group-icon-generators

also , i wish i could use a single file that auto-scales , so that i won't have multiple files.

here's another link that can help:
http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#screen-densities-and-icon-dimensions